# How to make main thread to wait until i call shutdown/ Notify on new fixed pool of threads in java

Tags: java, executorservice

I am creating 2 Async threads and running from main method using below code

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executorService.submit();
```

After submitting, I need to make main execution to wait until I call executorService.shutdown()/Notify explicitly to notify main thread to resume.

This to be achieve with out using time based sleep in main (`Thread.sleep(2000)`) and time based await function using executor object (`executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`).

Please help how can I achieve main thread to wait until I call either shutdown/notify from executor service object.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.Please edit the question and put relevant code in order to help experts to understand your issue

Comment: What's exactly the issue with `awaitTermination` ? It'd ensure your process won't be indefinitely stuck by a possible deadlock, for example. Also, if you can't estimate the maximum elapsed time beforehand, you might use Long.MAX_VALUE as the time value instead.